# Snakemake problems with Log

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm trying to write a Log param in my Snakefile, but I don't know what I'm missing. This is my code:

```
include:
    'config.py'

rule all:
    input:
        expand(WORK_DIR +"/trimmed/TFB{sample}_R{read_no}.fastq.gz.good",
        sample=SAMPLE_TFB ,read_no=['1', '2'])
rule fastp:
    input:
        R1= SAMPLES_DIR + "/TFB{sample}_R1.fastq.gz",
        R2= SAMPLES_DIR + "/TFB{sample}_R2.fastq.gz"
    output:
        R1out= WORK_DIR + "/trimmed/TFB{sample}_R1.fastq.gz.good",
        R2out= WORK_DIR + "/trimmed/TFB{sample}_R2.fastq.gz.good"
    log:
        log = WORK_DIR + "/logs/fastp/{sample}.html"
    shell:
        "fastp -i {input.R1} -I {input.R2} -o {output.R1out} -O {output.R2out} \
        -h {log.log}"
```

This is the error I get after executing the snakemake.

```
SyntaxError in line 16 of /work/users/leboralli/trofoZikaLincRNAs/scripts/Snakefile:
Colon expected after keyword log. (Snakefile, line 16)
```

I tried many options and nothing worked.

This software, fastp, has a param for logging: `-h`, with a `.html` output. Without the log my code works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your snakemake version? I tested it on v4.8.0 and your code works without error. Also, is `config.py` a snakemake file? AFAIK, only a snakemake file is allowed under `include` for modularization.

Comment: Note that it is better to use relative paths for input and output files. This makes your code much cleaner and more readable. Snakemake has a command line argument to specify the working directory.

Comment: @JeeYem the snakemake installed in our server here are v3.13.3, maybe this is the problem. I'll try to ask the admin to upgrade the version.
And thank you for the tip, @JohannesKöster! I'm a begginer trying to write a pipeline, so any tips are very valueble to me.